# Find $x\in\mathbb Z$ to $x-4\mid x\sqrt{x}-2x$

Tags: arithmetic

Find $x\in\mathbb Z$ to $x-4\mid x\sqrt{x}-2x$.
This is my idea:

Because $x\in\mathbb Z \Rightarrow x-4\in\mathbb Z$, so $x\sqrt{x}-2x\in\mathbb Z\Rightarrow x\sqrt{x}+2x\in\mathbb Z$

So to $x\in\mathbb Z$ to\begin{gather*}x-4\mid x\sqrt{x}-2x\Rightarrow x-4\mid(x\sqrt{x}-2x)(x\sqrt{x}+2x)\\\Rightarrow x-4\mid x^3-4x^2\Rightarrow x-4\mid x^2(x-4)\end{gather*}(true for all $x\in\mathbb Z$). But this is clearly wrong. I hope your help.

Comment: Divisibility in which ring?

Comment: $\frac{x\sqrt{x}-2x}{x-4}\in Z$

Comment: Thank you @Saad

Comment: What is ring @user10354138

Comment: @AndonisRyder You assumed that $x-4\vert x\sqrt{x}-2x$ is true for some $x$ and then you arrive at a contradiction. So unless there is an error in the manipulations that follow the assumption, the initial assumption is incorrect (so there is no value of $x$). I believe that the only solution is $x=0$. Also, when $x=0$, we can't follow the steps that you have mentioned since it would be equivalent to multiplying both sides of an equation by $0$.

Comment: how about $x\ne 0$

Comment: When $x\ne0$, the following steps are fine but we arrive at a contradiction. So our initial assumption (that there exists some $x$) is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $x\in \mathbb{Z}$,
$$x-4\vert x\sqrt{x}-2x \implies x\sqrt{x}-2x\in \mathbb{Z}\implies x\sqrt{x}\in \mathbb{Z}\implies x=p^2,\; p\in\mathbb{Z}$$
So, we have,
$$p^2-4\vert p^3-2p^2\implies p+2\vert p^2\implies p+2\vert p^2+4p+8\implies p+2\vert(p+2)^2+4\\ \therefore\; p+2\vert4$$
Therefore,
$$p\in\{2,0,-1,-3,-4,-6\}\implies x\in\{4,0,1,9,16,36\} $$
Plug the above values in the original divisibility condition and check which of these work.

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: why i tried again only 0.4 is correct?

Comment: When $x=4$, you get $0$ divides $0$ and when $x=0$, you get $-4$ divides $0$ and these are the only solutions.

Comment: So why do you find so many other solutions?

Comment: They are not all solutions. The valid solutions will belong to that set and you will have to verify if they work or not.